# How to handle latitude longitude data sent by android app in server

Tags: php, android, web

I have a working android application based on google maps. I get latitude longitude data from application every 10 second. Currently I am inserting latitude longitude data to database to users and manipulating it and sending response. This has contributed to huge load on server. Is there a better way to do this work. What technologies like servelets or jsp can I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not send the latitude longitude every 10 seconds. Have a minimum interval of 5 minutes.